# Silverlight bing maps component are no longer working

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, virtual-earth

We have an old web application in Silverlight, that is using Bing maps. It has been working until a few days ago.

It seems that the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files have been moved and are no longer available from http://dev.virtualearth.net. We get a 404 Not Found on those resources in the browser network log. Inside Visual Studio, the map is still showing in the XAML editor, but when the application is run, we just get an "Unable to contact Server. Please try again later" error message.

I can see that other users are reporting the same issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/799630/arcgis-map-services-stopped-loading.html

We are aware that Silverlight is unsupported and that it is bound to break in some manner, but we were kinda hoping to keep our project alive just a little bit longer. A few months back we saw the same issues, but after a few days, it started working again.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, any new?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is expected and there is no workaround. The silverlight map control end-of-life was announced 6 years ago, and the silverlight framework end of support was last year so there has been a very long timeframe for migration. Most browsers will not support silverlight any more either.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the Bing Maps Silverlight control was deprecated 6 years ago. However, I'm not aware of any work done to actually break it. I put together a resource on how to extend its life when the deprecation was announced, but that just directly retrieved map tiles and loaded them into the control. Double check the console for errors, it's possible that your Bing Maps credentials are not working. This could be due to your account being closed or exceeding free limits. If you have a Bing Maps license, contact maplic@microsoft.com to verify the license is up to date.

Another possible contributor is that Silverlight as a whole reached end of life last fall (near 6 months ago).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will check the license. The only errors we see, are the 404s on clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.